# Why is the block reward slightly higher than what it should be?

Tags: mining-reward

https://blockchain.info/block-index/143685

The block reward here is 50.04 BTC instead of 50. Why is this so? I notice many blocks have this slight excess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coinbase transaction(the transaction that pays miner bitcoins) gets bitcoins from two sources.

- Block reward: This part goes on declining like 50/25/12.5 and so-on in a pre-defined schedule
- transaction fees: This part is total sum of all transaction fees of all transactions in the that particular block. This is determined by market conditions.

Miner Income =  Block-reward + Transaction fees

Comment: Ah I see - so the transaction fees are considered newly generated coins? In other words, they are not considered as outputs from the transaction itself?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are no special outputs for fees. Fees is the inplicit difference between sum of inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3):

Transaction fees are not counted as newly generated coin. Here new is 50 but 04 is your total transaction fees. As a total reward it is 50.04 but newly generated only 50.